# Laravel doesn't load foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have a model called conversation with the value "from" and "to" being foreign keys to the user table.
ModelClass:

```
class Conversation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'from',
        'to'
    ];

    public function from() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from');
    }

    public function to() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'to');
    }
}
```

If I print the result for

```
$conversation = Conversation::with('to', 'from')->first();
```

I get this.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "from": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Maike",
        "created_at": "2015-07-31 21:33:05",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-01 09:19:51",
        "remember_token": null
    },
    "to": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Max",
        "created_at": "2015-07-31 21:32:53",
        "updated_at": "2015-07-31 21:32:53",
        "remember_token": null
    },
    "created_at": "2015-07-31 21:35:17",
    "updated_at": "2015-07-31 21:35:17"
}
```

But when I run then

$conversation->to

I get just the id of the given field, not the loaded user.

One possible solution is to write a getToUserAttribute function with

```
return $this->to()->get();
```

but I think there is a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your column name and your method name appeared to be the same.
when you do `$model->property` syntax, Laravel first tries to give you the value of the property you specified. This is exactly the case for you as you have `to` property in your model. And only after that it starts looking on relationships.

So yes, there are 2 workarounds for you:

1. change the name of the methods to something like `initiator` and `responder`
2. as you mentioned, you can do `$conversation->to()->get()`

also thiS comes to why you should always name your db fields like `to_id` and `from_id` and this is suggested approach and this is how Laravel by default treats the table. As this would allow you to write your relation

```
public function from() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

omitting the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution is very simple.
I just added an _id at the end of both columns and it worked fine. In my opinion the column is not allowed to have the same name as the Model you want to load in it. You don't overwrite your value (in my place "from" and "to") you just add another attribute.